# Quarkus Swagger-UI Authorization

Tags: java, swagger-ui, quarkus, bearer-token

Im currently working with Quarkus and Swagger-UI as delivered by quarkus-smallrye-openapi.
We have OIDC from Azure AD as security, which is currently not supported by Swagger-UI (see [Swagger-Docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/openid-connect-discovery/)), so I can't add the "real" authorization to swagger.
This means, I can't use Swagger since my endpoints are at least secured with `@RolesAllowed`.
We have an endpoint to fetch a mock-security token, but I don't know how to tell swagger to take this token.
Basically I want to tell swagger-ui "Here, I have this token, add it as `Authorization: Bearer XXX`to all requests", but I don't know how to do that in Quarkus.

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037662/quarkus-how-to-test-secured-api-endpoints-with-swagger-ui/64053958#64053958

Comment: You want this token to fetched automatically from OIDC or you want to place it and be used by your APIs in Swagger ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Register security scheme

```java
@Path("/sample")
@SecuritySchemes(value = {
        @SecurityScheme(securitySchemeName = "apiKey", 
                        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
                        scheme = "Bearer")}
)
public class SampleResource {
```

2. Mark the operation's security requirement with the scheme name registered.

```java
    @GET
    @SecurityRequirement(name = "apiKey")
    String hello() {
```

3. Authorize option should be now available on swagger page. Enter your mock api key here.
   [image]
4. Trigger the service from swagger ui. You could now see `Authorization: Bearer <VALUE>` header set in request.